# Database Insert Performance When Grabbing Items From Queue

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, rabbitmq

We're using **RabbitMQ** for storing lightweight messages that we eventually want to store in our **SQL Server database**. There will be times when the queue is empty and times when there is a spike of traffic - 30,000 messages.

We have a `C# console app` running in the same server.

Do we have the console app run every minute or so and grab a designated number of items off the queue for insertion into the database?  (taking manageable bites)

*OR*

Do we have the console app always "listen" and hammer items into the database as they come in? (more aggressive approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd go for the first approach.  During those "spike" times, you're going to be hammering the database with potentially 30,000 inserts.  Whilst this potentially could complete quite quickly (depending on many variables outside the scope of this question), we could do this a little smarter.

Firstly, by periodically polling, you can grab "x" messages from the queue and bulk insert them in a single go (performance-wise, you might want to tweak the the 2 variables here... polling time and how many you take from the queue).

One problem with this approach is that you might end up falling behind during busy periods.  So you could make your application change it's polling time based on how many it is receiving, whilst keeping between some min/max thresholds.  E.g. if you suddenly get a spike and grab 500 messages...  you might decrease your poll time.  If the next poll, you can still get thousand, do it again, decrease poll time.  As the number you are able to get drops off, you can then begin increasing your polling time under a particular threshold.

This would give you the best of both world imho and be reactive to the spikes/lull periods.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your requirement but I would create a service that calls SQLBulkCopy to that bulk inserts every couple of minutes. This is by far the fastests approach. Also if your Spike is 30k records I would not worry too much about falling behind.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

> > We have a C# console app running in the same server.

Why not a Service?

Comment: I will also check into the SQLBulkCopy and Windows Service options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have the console app always listen to the rabbitmq and then in the console app build your own queue for inserting into the database that way you can throttle the database insertion.  By doing this you can control the flow in busy a time by only allowing so many tasks at once and then in slow times you get a faster reaction then polling every so often.  The way I would do this is by raising an event and the you know there is something to do in the queue and you can check the queue length to see how many transactions you want to process.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Console Application, you could set up a **Windows Service**, and set up a timer on the service to poll **every n minutes**.  Take a look at the links below:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/189250/how-to-use-a-timer-in-windows-service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx

With a Windows Service, if the server is re-booted, the service can be set up to restart.